# Compare values in SQL, if match return true else false

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application which allows users to contact one another, look at it as a dating site.  I'm adding some security around the contact part, whereby the user can limit who can contact him/her either by setting a certain age / height range and gender.

Say for example I click on UserId-2 profiles, this will then make a call to the DB, pass in the ID or the chosen profile and also pass my ID in to, I then call my function passing in both of these values.  Function is as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Can_User_Contact] 
(
  @UserId1 int = 2, -- UserId
  @UserId2 int = 1 -- Requested by Id
)
  RETURNS bit
  AS
  BEGIN
  RETURN (

  SELECT CASE WHEN up.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS does_data_match
  FROM [user].User_Settings us
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User].[User_Profile] up ON us.UserId = @UserId1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId
  AND up.id = @UserId2 
  AND d.Height between ISNULL(us.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us.HeightTo, d.Height) 
  AND up.Age between ISNULL(us.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us.AgeTo, up.Age)
  AND up.Gender = ISNULL(us.Gender, up.Gender)

)  
END
```

Inside this function I compare the values UserId-2 has saved in the settings table to the values of my self by joining on the user profile table and the user details table, the problem with this is every time I execute it I get the following message:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I have two records in the setting table as shown here:

[image]

I'm only interested in the second record.

Can someone shed some light into what I might be doing wrong?

@UserId1 is the profile Id,
@UserId2 is the user who's requesting to view it.

Bare in mind, there may not be a record in the settings table for @UserId1 as well as this functionality is optional.

Comment: You need to return one value, but you are returning more then one rows. To test this change `SELECT` to `SELECT TOP 1` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single entry for `user_setting`,`User_Profile` and `User_Details` for each user, this should work.

Based on your result, it looks like a problem with your join conditions. Some of your join conditions should ideally be part of `WHERE` clause like `up.id = @UserId2`.

**Query**

```
  SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN us.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS does_data_match
  FROM [User].[User_Profile] up
  INNER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  [user].User_Settings us
  ON us.UserId = @UserId1 
  AND d.Height between ISNULL(us.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us.HeightTo, d.Height) 
  AND up.Age between ISNULL(us.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us.AgeTo, up.Age)
  AND up.Gender = ISNULL(us.Gender, up.Gender)
 WHERE up.id = @UserId2
ORDER BY up.id ASC
```

*Note: If assumption is true, then ideally `TOP` is not required. Just added it for additional safety*

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your query but yet it still returns true even though a certain user is of age 60 it should fail because her age doesn't fall into the brackets of 27 - 35, I have also commented out the other and statements to focus on the Age

Comment: oops, I just copied your case. forgot to change it to refer to `us.userid`. try the updated query

Answer (score 1):

multiple rows are being returned by `SELECT` query.
Since you are interested in a single value use like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Can_User_Contact] 
        (
          @UserId1 int = 2, -- UserId
          @UserId2 int = 1 -- Requested by Id
        )
        RETURNS bit
        AS
        BEGIN
          RETURN 
          (
            SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS  
            (  
                SELECT 1 FROM [user].User_Settings us1
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User].[User_Profile] up ON up.id = @UserId2
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User].[User_Details] d ON up.Id = d.UserId 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN [user].[User_Settings] us2 ON us2.UserId=up.id
              WHERE  
                  d.Height between ISNULL(us1.HeightFrom, d.height) and ISNULL(us1.HeightTo, d.Height) 
                  AND us2.Age between ISNULL(us1.AgeFrom, up.age) and ISNULL(us1.AgeTo, up.Age)
                  AND us1.Gender = ISNULL(us2.Gender, up.Gender)
                  AND up.Id IS NOT NULL 
                  AND  us1.UserId = @UserId1
            )   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS does_data_match  
        END
```

Comment: That seemed to of got rid of the error, the issue I now get is if I target the first record in my picture I attached, the UserId2 age is 60 yet my function returns 1 i.e true when it should fail. Because UserId2 age does not fall between 27 and 35

Comment: @CodeRatchet Updated your query. Notice that I'm using `d.age` and `d.Gender` instead of `up.Age` and `up.Gender`

Comment: age and gender are apart of the user profile table unfortunately.